# Stored procedure unique constraints not respected

Tags: postgresql

Table "Account" receives the FK from "Student" and has a unique constraint *email*.
Table "Student" has a unique constrain on the *username*.

I am building a stored procedure to add a new account if the student(user) doesn't exist.
The function below works one way only. It recognizes when email already exists, not allowing to add.
But, if I change the email, it does not recognize the username repeated.

Problem: If the username is already there, I do not want to add it to that table. Username and email are uniques.

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add_students(
    usern varchar(10),
    user_pass varchar(15),
    start_d timestamp,
    first_n varchar(40),
    last_n varchar(50),
    e_mail varchar(50))

RETURNS boolean AS $$
DECLARE
did_insert boolean := false;
found_count integer;
the_account_id integer;
BEGIN
SELECT account_id INTO the_account_id
FROM account s
WHERE s.user_password=user_pass AND s.start_date=start_d and s.username like usern
LIMIT 1;
IF the_account_id IS NULL THEN
INSERT INTO account (username, user_password, start_date)
VALUES (usern, user_pass, start_d)
RETURNING account_id INTO the_account_id;
did_insert := true;
END IF;
-- Note: this is a notice, not an error as in some programming languages
RAISE NOTICE 'Account found %', the_account_id;
INSERT INTO student (first_name, last_name, email, account_id)
VALUES (first_n, last_n, e_mail, the_account_id);
RETURN did_insert;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

[image: Account table]

[image: Student table]

I was expecting to see the student table with only one result per FK(account_id). Does this example make sense?

Comment: account_id isn't unique in student, so postgres has no reason to reject these records...
If its OneToOne you could have taken account_id as FK and primary key for student

Comment: Setting the FK account_id Unique, did the trick. Thanks a lot for the help!